# IOS- how to set frames for UIscrollview for universal devices on storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I am working on a project in which I have to use `UIScrollView` for page scrolling.
i want scrollview for universal devices(iPhone, iPad) I don't know how to set frame for it please help

I used some methods but they are not working I use the following code in `viewDidLoad` method how to set it's frame for all devices

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mainscrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    mainscrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
    mainscrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
    mainscrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:mainscrollview];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: First of all, the call to `[super viewDidLoad]` should be the first call in your implementation of `viewDidLoad`. Secondly, you mention `storyboard` in your question title, but it seems that you are adding the scroll view from code - so which one is it? :) And last - you never set any frame for the scroll view - you should either use `initWithFrame:` or do `mailscrollview.frame = (...)`.

Comment: did you try CGRect screenSize = [ [UIScreen mainScreen]bound];
[mainscrollView setframe:screenSize];

Answer (score 1):

http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/ see this link you will get some help.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on SO - you should at least cite the most relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set `UIScrollView` frame for all device.

```
mainscrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the space avaiable for the view controller (i.e. the navigation bar). It would be better to do it something like this : `CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)`

Comment: @Losiowaty this is work for me navigation also because UINavigation adjust size automatic base on translucent property.